# How to pass javascript session to database through hidden input field?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i want to submit the javascript session through hidden input text field.How can i change the value of textfield to session value stored?

View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('test/score') ?>
<input type='hidden' name='xp' value='"sessionStorage.score"'></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-dark bt mb-5" placeholder="img">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Controller

```
public function score(){
 $data8['xp'] = $this->input->post('xp', TRUE);
            $this->upload_model->xpup($data8);
 }
```

Model

```
function xpup($data8)                               
{$insert_data['xp'] = $data8['xp'];
$query = $this->db->insert('users', $insert_data);
return;                                     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a hidden input value from a sessionStorage, try to modify the html input like this :

```html
<input type='hidden' name='xp' id="scoreInput" value='' />
```

And add the javascript codes :

```js
<script>
    let score = sessionStorage.getItem("score");
    document.getElementById("scoreInput").value = score;
</script>
```